# Detecting USB drive insertion and removal using windows service and c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, wmi

Looking into possibility of making an USB distributed application
that will autostart on insertion of an USB stick and shutdown when removing the stick

Will use .Net and C#.
Looking for suggestion how to approach this using C#?

---

Update: Two possible solutions implementing this as a service.
- override WndProc
or
- using WMI query with ManagementEventWatcher

Comment: Good question on the service trapping this event.  My first thought is  you have to mark your service as "allow to interact with desktop" and then create a hidden window.  Safer option is probably to create a windows app that runs at startup - it can create the window and then communicate to the svc

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003822/how-to-detect-a-usb-drive-has-been-plugged-in

Comment: I made a NuGet packet that works on Windows, MacOS and Linux: https://github.com/Jinjinov/Usb.Events

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use WMI, it is easy and it works a lot better than WndProc solution with services.

Here is a simple example:

```
using System.Management;

ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
watcher.Query = query;
watcher.Start();
watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
```

Comment: That works fine but How can I get drive letter of inserted USB?

Comment: [This article](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/monitoring-volume-change-events-in-powershell-using-wmi/) seems to be getting this information in Powershell. Shouldn't be too hard to translate that to C#.

Comment: In your event handler, `e.NewEvent.Properties["DriveName"].Value.ToString()`

Comment: the query is clearly for volume changes, which has nothing to do usb added/removed. It doesn't even work for volume changes, at least on my system

Comment: using the above query is eating cpu resources, any idea why wmi causes this issue?

Comment: Does this instantly trigger the event or does it check in an interval? / Is it possible for another Program / the user to read/write files from the drive before the event fires?

Answer (score 57):

This works well for me, plus you can find out more information about the device.

```
using System.Management;

private void DeviceInsertedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
    foreach (var property in instance.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " = " + property.Value);
    }
}

private void DeviceRemovedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
    foreach (var property in instance.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " = " + property.Value);
    }
}            

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    WqlEventQuery insertQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'");

    ManagementEventWatcher insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(insertQuery);
    insertWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceInsertedEvent);
    insertWatcher.Start();

    WqlEventQuery removeQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'");
    ManagementEventWatcher removeWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(removeQuery);
    removeWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceRemovedEvent);
    removeWatcher.Start();

    // Do something while waiting for events
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000000);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Doesn't fire multiple events like some of the other answers here on insertion/removal.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree with @samuelAndThe, this seems the best aproach.
If you are looking for also detect changes to hard drives and not only usb drives you can use the 'Win32_DiskDrive' class

Comment: `private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)`, why do you have `(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)`???(I committed an edit suggestion for this.)

Comment: Will this run on mono? Just asking, because started recently with that, and wmi is ms pure.

Comment: Everything is awesome but please remove that Thread.Sleep ^_^

Comment: What's the purpose of Thread.Sleep? The DeviceInsertedEvent still fires event after the BackgroundWorker call ends after this sleep times out

Comment: I think that Thread.Sleep is there to simulate a long application code. You can simply remove it.

Comment: Is there any way to detect **Any** USB device in this method? As you know other answers fire multiple events which is not good.

Answer (score 26):

Adding to VitalyB's post.

To raise an event where **ANY** USB device is inserted, use the following:

```
var watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
var query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
watcher.Query = query;
watcher.Start();
```

This will raise an event whenever a USB device is plugged. It even works with a National Instruments DAQ that I'm trying to auto-detect.

Comment: @Lee Taylor That works fine but How can I get drive letter of inserted USB?

Comment: @NeverQuit - I only edited the question, ask @Syn! Also, if you have a new question then feel free to create one.

Comment: @Syn That works fine but How can I get drive letter of inserted USB?

Comment: Hi it works great for USB insertion!
the above comment with 
"SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2"
I don't know why but it doesn't work for me.
I want the event to run both for insertion and removal.
Do you now the line string which will make it happen?
or where I can see all the string which the wqleventQuery receive?
It's not listed on the MSDN  wqleventQuery  CTOR page ..

Comment: For removal, you just need to do `WHERE EventType = 2 OR EventType = 3`. `EventType` of `2` means addition, `3` means removal, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-devicechangeevent#members

Answer (score 21):

VitalyB's answer does't cover remove of the device. I changed it a bit to trigger the event both when media is **inserted** and **removed** and also code to get the drive letter of the inserted media.

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace MonitorDrives
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum EventType
        {
            Inserted = 2,
            Removed = 3
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
            WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2 or EventType = 3");

            watcher.EventArrived += (s, e) =>
            {
                string driveName = e.NewEvent.Properties["DriveName"].Value.ToString();
                EventType eventType = (EventType)(Convert.ToInt16(e.NewEvent.Properties["EventType"].Value));

                string eventName = Enum.GetName(typeof(EventType), eventType);

                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", DateTime.Now, driveName, eventName);
            };

            watcher.Query = query;
            watcher.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, but for some reason it's firing the event multiple times each time I plug in or out a device - do you know why this might be and how to prevent it?

Comment: As you haven't posted your code its hard to tell, but may be you are attaching the event more than once.

Comment: this is not a ***full*** code!!! so you need to replace several lines of VitalyB's answer to this.

Comment: Nice enhancements Ashkan, it's nice to know when a drive is ejected too.

Answer (score 6):

A little bit edit on all above answer:

```
using System.Management;

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bgwDriveDetector.DoWork += bgwDriveDetector_DoWork;
        bgwDriveDetector.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void DeviceInsertedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string driveName = e.NewEvent.Properties["DriveName"].Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(driveName + " inserted");
    }

    private void DeviceRemovedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string driveName = e.NewEvent.Properties["DriveName"].Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(driveName + " removed");
    }

    void bgwDriveDetector_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var insertQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
        var insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(insertQuery);
        insertWatcher.EventArrived += DeviceInsertedEvent;
        insertWatcher.Start();

        var removeQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 3");
        var removeWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(removeQuery);
        removeWatcher.EventArrived += DeviceRemovedEvent;
        removeWatcher.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: DeviceName is not found in the e.NewEven.Properties.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx) to detect insertion events. It's a little bit more complicated than monitoring for WM_CHANGEDEVICE messages, but it does not require a window handle which may be useful if you are running in the background as a service.

Comment: @John Conrad: +1 WMI is a good choice. Also found a SO topic on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704/wmi-and-win32devicechangeevent-wrong-event-type-returned

Comment: Actually WMI is much simpler solution. I'm posting it below as another solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try [**WM_CHANGEDEVICE**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/devicevolumemonitor.aspx) handling.

Answer (score 4):

My complete answer can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/dtwk2/42d3aa1d6f42b6b106228c472272b966) as a gist

I found the answer to determining the drive letter from the serial # from this question/answer
[How to get the drive letter of USB device using WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938686/how-to-get-the-drive-letter-of-usb-device-using-wmi/60548941#60548941)

And I modified Phil Minor's code to make it reactive:

```
   public class UsbDetector : IUsbDetector
    {
        private const string Query = "SELECT * FROM {0} WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'";
        private const string CreationEvent = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
        private const string DeletionEvent = "__InstanceDeletionEvent";
        private const int ReplayNumber = 1;

        private readonly Subject<USBDeviceInfo> adds = new Subject<USBDeviceInfo>();
        private readonly Subject<USBDeviceInfo> removes = new Subject<USBDeviceInfo>();

        public UsbDetector()
        {
            var bgwDriveDetector = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgwDriveDetector.DoWork += DoWork;
            bgwDriveDetector.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        public IObservable<USBDeviceInfo> Adds => adds.AsObservable();

        public IObservable<USBDeviceInfo> Removes => removes.AsObservable();


        private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            SubscribeToEvent(CreationEvent, adds);
            SubscribeToEvent(DeletionEvent, removes);
        }

        private static void SubscribeToEvent(string eventType, IObserver<USBDeviceInfo> observer)
        {
            WqlEventQuery wqlEventQuery = new WqlEventQuery(string.Format(Query, eventType));
            ManagementEventWatcher insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(wqlEventQuery);

            var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArrivedEventHandler, EventArrivedEventArgs>(
                h => insertWatcher.EventArrived += h,
                h => insertWatcher.EventArrived -= h).Replay(ReplayNumber);

            observable.Connect();
            observable.Select(a => a.EventArgs).Select(MapEventArgs).Subscribe(observer);
            insertWatcher.Start();
        }


        private static USBDeviceInfo MapEventArgs(EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];

            string deviceId = (string)instance.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID");
            string serialNr = deviceId.Substring(deviceId.LastIndexOf('\\')).Replace("\\", "");
            char driveLetter = GetDriveLetter(serialNr).First();

            return new USBDeviceInfo(deviceId, serialNr, driveLetter);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what we did with C# .Net 4.0 under a WPF app.   We are still searching for an answer to "how to tell WHICH device type was inserted/removed", but this is a start:

```
    using System.Windows.Interop;
...
public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    ...
    public MainWindow()
    {
    ...
    }

    //============================================================
    // WINDOWS MESSAGE HANDLERS
    // 

    private const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;  // int = 537
    private const int DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES = 0x00000004; 

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
        {
            ReadDongleHeader();
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

}
```

Comment: Any improvements as to figuring out which device was inserted?

Comment: @Kevin this can easily be found elsewhere to get the list of devices. Here is a full solution which I got to first. Only WM_DEVICECHANGE is fired for me. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ea183afd-d070-4abd-8e00-a1784fdfedc5/detecting-usb-device-insertion-and-removal?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
  public  class usbState
    {
       public usbState()
        {

        }

   private void DeviceInsertedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
   {
       ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
       foreach (var property in instance.Properties)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " = " + property.Value);
       }
   }

   private void DeviceRemovedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
   {
       ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
       foreach (var property in instance.Properties)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " = " + property.Value);
       }
   } 

    public  void bgwDriveDetector_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        WqlEventQuery insertQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'");

        ManagementEventWatcher insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(insertQuery);
        insertWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceInsertedEvent);
        insertWatcher.Start();

        WqlEventQuery removeQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'");
        ManagementEventWatcher removeWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(removeQuery);
        removeWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceRemovedEvent);
        removeWatcher.Start();
    }

}



class Class1
{
       private static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          usbState  usb= new usbState();



          BackgroundWorker bgwDriveDetector = new BackgroundWorker();
          bgwDriveDetector.DoWork += usb.bgwDriveDetector_DoWork;
          bgwDriveDetector.RunWorkerAsync();
          bgwDriveDetector.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
          bgwDriveDetector.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

         // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
           Console.ReadKey();

       }





}

}
```