# Why is the command prompt disappearing after loading?

Tags: c#, linq, command-prompt

With the code below, the command prompt disappears almost immediately after appearing. Shouldn't this code display all the removable drives being used?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
             .Where(drive => drive.IsReady && drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable);
            Console.WriteLine("Removable drives being used:", drives);
        } 
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `Console.Read();` at the end of `Main`.

Comment: When you debug, do you hit F5 or Crtl + F5?

Comment: `Ctrl` + `F5` starts your application without debugger. It behaves differently in this mode; the command windows remains open and says "press any key to continue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
 DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
 foreach(DriveInfo dv in drives)          
 {              
        Console.WriteLine("drive Name:{0}", dv.Name);      
 }    
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I get `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator1[System.IO.DriveInfo]`

Comment: Please visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much, the command prompt does not display the drives though.

Comment: have you visited the above link..it may give you an idea regarding drives info which you want to display...

Comment: Thank you Amol, yes I did, the Name is the right info but unfortunately it doesn't show up in the command prompt. I don't get the string `"drive Name:{0}"` either actually.

Comment: That is weird..it shud hav been worked...Pls debug your application and see wether you are getting DriveInfo..

Comment: Thanks Amol , sorry would it be possible for you to paste the whole updated code in your reply. Not sure if I need to keep: `var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives() .Where(drive => drive.IsReady && drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable);`

Comment: Use the same code from the Msdn site or remove ".Where(drive => drive.IsReady && drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable);" and try again...

Answer (score 2):

Try a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end. Windows closes command windows as soon as running applications have terminated.

Comment: Thank you! The command stays but does not display the drives :(

Comment: You are welcome. Seems you got a working solution to display the drives now.

Answer (score 2):

Because it executes your command and exists. You can give it an instruction to wait for any keypress before closing.

For Example:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Updated:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
         .Where(drive => drive.IsReady && drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable);
         foreach(DriveInfo di in drives)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Removable drives being used:", di.Name);
         {

    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works but the drives are not showing. Do you know why?

Comment: What is the type returned by GetDrives(); ?

Comment: On this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives) where can I see the return type? When placing a breakpoint the drives variable is `null` which probably explains the problem

Comment: The method Returns an Array of DriveInfo, so the console cannot print out anything, it can only print strings. That's why you need to make a foreach loop.

Comment: I am getting an iEnumerable. I have tried the following loop `for (int i = 0; i < drives.length; i++){Console.WriteLine("Removable drives being used", drives[i]);}` but got the error that it is an iEnumerable so it doesn't contain length..etc...

Comment: I've updated the method above, and dont ask me if i am sure just read your link. Return Value
Type: System.IO.DriveInfo[]
An array of type DriveInfo that represents the logical drives on a computer.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for that. I am still not getting the drives unfortunately.