# The name 'WM_DEVICECHANGE' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, windows-messages

I am trying to detect a usb arrival event . I tried to override `wndproc()` for getting my messages. But I am facing an error by windows messages.

The error is :

```
The name 'WM_DEVICECHANGE' does not exist in the current context

The name 'DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL' does not exist in the current context
```

Also this is the code I am tried.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;         
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles; 

namespace USBCheckerApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool bDeviceFound = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!bDeviceFound)
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }


        }
        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
                    if (m.WParam == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("MEDIA FOUND");
                    }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Added so that you could suggest any updations in the same.
Thanks

Comment: Show your code here. People can't read your mind.

Comment: @SonerGönül  I just read yours .. I was editing

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect a USB drive has been plugged in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003822/how-to-detect-a-usb-drive-has-been-plugged-in) - you forgot to copy in the constants that are mentioned in the answer from Onsightfree

Comment: @Petesh You can argue. But it is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to declare and define the values of the constants:

```
private const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;
private const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
```

Comment: Actually not I am a beginner in c# but had some fun in c++ :) . Thats wht. Let me check ur answer