# Uniquely identifying a pendrive

Tags: c#, usb-flash-drive

I am working on [USB devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877851/the-name-wm-devicechange-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) and can identify a usb device. But I have a theoretical question.Is it shows any usb device like portable cd drive  or specifically  flash drives? I could nt check all possibilities due to lack of these hardwares :). Is there any method to identify if it is a flash drive or another usb device.

Please don't beat with what you have tried. I [googled](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&q=identify+a+flash+drive+c%23&spell=1&sa=X&ei=Fp5jUcevPM3trQeIxYD4Ag&ved=0CCsQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44990110,d.bmk&fp=5a8723a815cf09ab&biw=1280&bih=838) regarding same but because of my least experience I couldn't find any.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271907/how-to-detect-using-c-sharp-if-a-pendrive-is-plugged-into-a-usb-port?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the class `USBSerialNumber`

```
USBSerialNumber usb = new USBSerialNumber();
string serial = usb.getSerialNumberFromDriveLetter("f:\");
MessageBox.Show(serial);
```

Each pendrive has serial number which is unique.

You can use this class for this purpose.

**Download it from following link:**

http://www.cfdan.com/posts/Retrieving_Non-Volatile_USB_Serial_Number_Using_C_Sharp.cfm

Comment: I hope Every usb device(bth device,mouse, etc) has a serial number. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yeah , each usb device has it. so pendrive also.

Comment: so will this  identify a generic pen drive? in this case we need to know the usb device serial number right?

Comment: serial number is written in each pendrive. and no need to know it in this case.