# Using WndProc override to detect when USB attached or detached

Tags: c#, .net, usb, windows-messages

This question got me to where I am now [The name 'WM_DEVICECHANGE' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877851/the-name-wm-devicechange-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

but I am having an issue detecting the proper messages when they happen, and I am not sure if the message codes I am using wrong or if I made a mistake elsewhere, but I just want to know how I can use the overridden method to detect ONLY USB attach or detach, or if maybe there is a more conclusive article somewhere to show me explicitly what each code within WM_DEVICECHANGE is?

```
    private const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
    private const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000; // system detected a new device
    private const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004; //device was removed

    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
                if (m.WParam.ToInt64() == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
                    MessageBox.Show("TEST");
                if (m.WParam.ToInt64() == DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE)
                    MessageBox.Show("DETACHED");
                break;
        }

    }
```

my issue is if I try to follow the example in the question asked above, I get an error of "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.IntPtr' and 'int'" but if I leave it as shown in my sample code then it doesn't trigger because the number in WParam never matches that in DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL or DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE

Comment: You know what! you solved an issue i was facing from 1AM to 8AM with your very simple code, i can't find a way to thank you also stack community. thanks god :)

Answer (score 0):

`ToInt64()` will just return the address(or handle) as an integer. I believe you are wanting to retrieve the value stored there, in which case you would do

```
if(Marshal.ReadInt64(m.wParam) == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
//and so on
```

Marshal is in the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

Also make sure that is where the value is supposed to be pulled from, i.e. could be the high word or low word or something and not all 64/32 bits.

Comment: I tried your solution and then I tried checking all the fields within m for a number that matched what DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL was and NONE of them matched after a USB was inserted and the WM_DEVICECHANGE event was hit. Is it possible I have defined DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL with the wrong codes? If so then how did they work properly for anyone else?

Comment: @JBeck You have the right code. Try ReadInt32() instead of ReadInt64()

Comment: Still nothing using if(Marshal.ReadInt32(m.wParam) == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL) it is never getting a number the same as DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL. Is the defined value for it really supposed to be 0x8000?

Comment: @JBeck Did you register your app to receive notifications? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx

Comment: Oh shoot! No I do not think I did that. How would I go about doing that in C#?

Comment: @JBeck Take a look here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.registerdevicenotification Basically you will call it on loading your app. You may have to find a tutorial if this doesn't have enough info.