# Portable device detection using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, wpd

I have a problem detecting portable devices, specifically samsung phone or iphone.
I need to develop a program that will start once the detection of a portable plug-in and stop, once plugged out.

I've been trying this code, but only works with usb devices with storage, and not on portable device.

```
private void DeviceInsertedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
    foreach (var property in instance.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " = " + property.Value);
    }
}

void DeviceRemovedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
    foreach (var property in instance.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " = " + property.Value);
    }
}            

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    WqlEventQuery insertQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'");

    ManagementEventWatcher insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(insertQuery);
    insertWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceInsertedEvent);
    insertWatcher.Start();

    WqlEventQuery removeQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'");
    ManagementEventWatcher removeWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(removeQuery);
    removeWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceRemovedEvent);
    removeWatcher.Start();

    // Do something while waiting for events
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000000);
}
```

please help. thanks

Comment: Off topic, but what do you hope to achieve by `Sleep`ing for 5.5 hours?

Comment: sorry about the sleep part. i will remove it. i just need a way to detect the insert and remove of the portable device.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6003915/1324033) help at all? (from one of the related questions on the right), It may be worth noting if you only intend to look for devices via usb, (i.e not bluetooth)

Comment: What i really need to detect is the plug in of a Samsung phone/ IPhone

Comment: Which Samsung phone? Android or WP? After pluggin it in, is it visible as a device in explorer or anywhere in windows? The WM_DEVICECHANGE message ought to help. In the post Sayse links to are many interesting links. (Not the accepted answer, though, as ever so often..)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
System.IO.DriveInfo [] drives = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives ();
foreach (System.IO.DriveInfo drive in drives)
{
  if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
  {
    Console.WriteLine ("Found removable drive {0}", drive.Name);
  }
}
```

For More about [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx)

Comment: this only works with usb devices. not portable devices like samsung phone

Comment: Specifically it only works with Mass Storage devices, not those using Windows Portable Device (aka MTP: Media Transfer Protocol).