# c# USB plugged\unplugged event

Tags: c#, port, serial-communication

I was wondering if there is an option(in c#) to set an event handler which would run each time one of the USB ports are plugged/unplugged.

Comment: This answer has decent solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6003822/153923

Comment: That duplicate covers USB thumb drives. Replacing creation of `Win32_VolumeChangeEvent` instances with `Win32_PnPEntity` instances will allow any device change – including USB – to be detected.