# How to detect mobile device(Iphone) connected to USB in windows forms application?

Tags: c#, ios, mobile, usb

I am developing a windows forms application which should communicate with Mobile devices(First with iOS devices, later with Android). Communication can only be through Usb port. Which is the best way to detect if the mobile device is connected, and if it is possible to connect windows application with only a specific mobile application.
I hope someone can help me!

Thank you

Comment: May help: [A USB Library to Detect USB Devices](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60579/A-USB-Library-to-Detect-USB-Devices)

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003822/how-to-detect-a-usb-drive-has-been-plugged-in

Comment: Thank you, I will get a look on that

Comment: Do you know if it will be possible to access to a specific mobile application installed in the iPhone?For example to access from windows forms application to whatsapp data

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but I recently wrote a blog post explaining how I was able to achieve this

http://thecodewash.blogspot.com/2017/05/communicating-with-your-ios-app-over.html

To answer your question (so this answer isn't just a link), yes it definitely is possible to achieve this utilizing the USB Multiplexing Daemon (usbmuxd) program that is usually installed as part of iTunes. This program can create a socket connection to your iOS device through the USB cable, and allow you to communicate via that socket connection like you would any other socket. The link goes into much more detail.

Hope this helps anyone else looking for answers regarding this.