# How to detect, when a juul started charging? Over ubs (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, usb

I have a juul, a charger, and a pc. The pc has usb ports. Thats clear.

When i plug a mouse, keyboard or any HID device, the pc can recognise these, but when i plug the charger, nothing happened.
I'm try to watch the connected usb devices, with the "USBDeview" by NirSoft. The software cant list the charger.

How can I detect, when any specified stuff connected via usb? Now the "stuff" is the juul charger.

Thanks for any help, I tried to make it simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a USB drive has been plugged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003822/how-to-detect-a-usb-drive-has-been-plugged-in)

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a charger, it has nothing to do with the USB bus aside from drawing 5V from its power. I.e. it may only have DC power pins (+, -), without the data pins (D+, D-). In which case, your OS won't notice anything was plugged in.

[image]

Image from Wikipedia

Comment: This charger and the juul has data pins. But i think it is for install firmware and test in the factory.

Comment: @Nightels according to [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/juul/comments/84rmmf/anyone_else_hear_the_juul_and_computer_communicate/) some older versions may not have the data pins, while some newer ones may. If your OS doesn't react when it's plugged in then yours probably isn't connected internally, even though the pins are there. This is just a guess (I don't even vape bro)