# how to find if the USB is connected to computer or Not using c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a small desktop application in which i have to check whether the USB is connected to the computer or NOT? Please help me with this. I have searched hard on this but i am not satisfied. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't searched enough, then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620144/detecting-usb-drive-insertion-and-removal-using-windows-service-and-c-sharp

Comment: Are you trying to detect a USB drive?  Or some other USB device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the way to go would be to enumerate the usb devices connected to the computer then searching for the one you want. There is another question on SO [about usb enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices)

Comment: Thanks Sir. I think i have to go from this approach with the SELECT statement.