# Detecting Hardware Insertion and/or Removal on other Systems in the network using C#

Tags: c#

I wrote a small software to detect USB-Insertions on my PC.
First as an Console-Application then as a Windows-Service.
Using these links:

- [detecting usb-device insertion and removal in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975946/detecting-usb-device-insertion-and-removal-in-c-sharp)
- [Detecting Hardware Insertion and/or Removal](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14500/Detecting-Hardware-Insertion-and-or-Removal)
- [Detecting USB drive insertion and removal using windows service and c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620144/detecting-usb-drive-insertion-and-removal-using-windows-service-and-c-sharp)

Both works well. So far so good.
BUT:

Now I want to write the Application to detect USB-Inserts on other Systems in the network. I couldn't find anything using google so I hope you have an idea how I could get for example DeviceChange Logs from other systems.

Comment: You would need the other systems on the network to publish that info in some way.

Comment: Is there no way to register myself for the device change notifications of other systems?

Comment: Only if you can run code on the other systems. So each systems would need an app that listens for "device notifications" and publish this info to your "server" or wait to be polled for that info.

Comment: @npit, I know this old question but can you please share the code for both Console Application and Windows Service?