# Write a script to automatically write files to USB drive on plugin

Tags: python, usb-drive

I am more of a Web Developer, with basic Java skills. Python, C++, .NET are all pretty foreign to me but I have written simple things in all 3 languages.

I have a unique and kind of silly idea of writing a script that performs the following task:
-In the event that a USB flash drive is plugged in, check the contents of a specific folder on the computer (Like documents/school/CSE)
-If any of the files in said folder differ from the files on the USB drive, write the files to the drive

I have no idea where to start, but I don't imagine this is a complicated script to write/idea to execute.

Comment: Which particular part of this task do you need help with?

Comment: It sounds like something that would differ, depending on the operating system.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1425/)

Comment: If you intend your program to work for windows users, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620144/detecting-usb-drive-insertion-and-removal-using-windows-service-and-c-sharp . Python is not a requirement for this task as far as I can tell.

Comment: Im on Windows, and looking at the above link has got me started, so thanks!!!