# Autorun batch file through eject command

Tags: batch-file, usb-drive

Is it possible for a batch script on my local machine (e.g. in `D:\ Batch files\1.bat`) to run after I insert or eject a USB drive?

Comment: Not really possible with a batch file alone.  You need some means to [monitor for USB events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620144/detecting-usb-drive-insertion-and-removal-using-windows-service-and-c-sharp).  Bottom line: executing the batch file is trivial, determining when to execute the batch file is not.

Comment: 1. please select the correct tags for your question, as [tag:batch-file] and [tag:spring-batch] are totally different things; tag [tag:batch-processing] does not apply at all; 2. share what you have tried so far and precisely describe where you are stuck; remember that SO is not a free code writing service;

Comment: Should be migrated to superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Preliminaries:

- Right-click `Computer` icon, select `Manage`, go to `Services`,
  select `Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework` and make sure it's running and its Startup Type is set to `Automatic` or `Automatic (Delayed Start)`.

Now go to `Task Scheduler`:

1. Make a new task, name it `MyCoolBatch on USB-connect`.
2. On `Triggers` tab add a new trigger:

   - `On an event` in the first dropdown box
   - `Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational` in the Log dropdown
   - `DriverFrameworks-UserMode` in the Source
   - `2003` in the Event ID (this is USB connect event)

   [image: new trigger screenshot]
3. On `Actions` tab make a new action and select your batch file.
   You can add a parameter like `plugged`.

Repeat steps 1-3 with an Event ID `2100` (the USB disconnect event) and a batch file parameter like `ejected` so, assuming the same batch file is used, you can check if device was connected/ejected:

```
if "%1"=="plugged" .........
if "%1"=="ejected" .........
```

<sup>Based on [The Windows 7 Event Log and USB Device Tracking](http://dfstream.blogspot.com/2014/01/the-windows-7-event-log-and-usb-device.html) article.</sup>

Comment: i am using windows 8.1 .and Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework isn't running...so what to do now? @wOxxOm

Comment: @Sourabh, I don't understand what is the problem and why haven't tried [googling it](https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+start+windows+service).