# WMI InstanceCreationEvent not fired after windows hibernate

Tags: c#, windows-services, usb, wmi

I create two handlers to receive USB device plug/unplug events, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19435744/3576052).

```
private void RegisterUSBEvents()
{
    WqlEventQuery insertQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'");
    ManagementEventWatcher insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(insertQuery);
    insertWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceInsertedEvent);
    insertWatcher.Start();
    WqlEventQuery removeQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'");
    ManagementEventWatcher removeWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(removeQuery);
    removeWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceRemovedEvent);
    removeWatcher.Start();
}
```

I could receive any USB plug or unplug event using above code.

For most PCs, after windows wake up from hibernation, my app will receive a `InstanceDeletionEvent`, following by a `InstanceCreationEvent` for a USB device.

However, on few computers, after windows hibernates and wakes up, I could only receive a `InstanceDeletionEvent`, but no `InstanceCreationEvent` for the same device. The USB device is leaved on the USB port untouched.

If I close and restart my app, or unplug/plug the same device, the above code becomes working again.

Is there any problem causing a USB device fire `InstanceDeletionEvent` but not fire `InstanceCreationEvent` after hibernation in certain environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, but seems not software-related.

On those problematic PC, if the USB device is plugged at the USB port **directly on the motherboard**, the `InstanceDeletionEvent` and `InstanceCreationEvent` would fire properly after wake from hibernation, at over 95% working chance.

If the USB device is plugged at front panel USB port, there is about 75% chance that `InstanceCreationEvent` will not fire after wake.

Maybe it is a faulty hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a registry entry called **[ResetOnResume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-device-specific-registry-settings)** which will force the USB driver stack to reset the device on wake. It's disabled by default which would explain the issue your having after waking from hibernation on some PC's.

> **ResetOnResume**
>
> Indicates whether the USB driver stack must reset the device when the
>   port resumes from a sleep cycle.

Comment: I checked one of the problematic PC. The registry entry of usb device does not contain a `ResetOnResume` entry.

Comment: You create it as per the article.